# Does independence need to be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

In the sentence 
When Mexico won its independence from Spain,
 it became easier for people to immigrate to Texas.
Would independence be capitalized?

Comment: Is it a proper noun? If so, yes.

Comment: No! It is not a name or a title. Lots of advice at: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/using-capital-letters

Answer (score 1):

No 'independence' should not be capitalized like that. It is not a proper noun.

You would capitalize 'independence' if it were part of a proper noun phrase such as 'Independence Day' or 'Declaration of Independence'.